# Lower semicontinuous function is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $(X, \mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be measure space such that $\mathfrak{M}$ contains all Borel sets of $X$. Let $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ be lower semicontinuous function (LSC). Prove that $f$ is measurable.

**Proof:** Let $U$ be an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ then $U=\bigsqcup \limits_{i=1}^{\infty}I_j$ where $I_j$ open intervals of form $(a_j,b_j)$. Then $f^{-1}(U)=\bigsqcup \limits_{i=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}(I_j)$.

Let's take a look at $$f^{-1}(I_j)=f^{-1}((a_j,b_j))=\{x:a_j<f(x)<b_j\}=\{x:f(x)>a_j\}\cap \{x:f(x)<b_j\}$$
Since $$\{x:f(x)<b_j\}=f^{-1}((-\infty, b_j))=f^{-1}\left(\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty,b_j-\frac{1}{n}]\right)=\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}f^{-1}\left((-\infty,b_j-1/n]\right)=$$$$=\bigcup \limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(f^{-1}\left((b_j-1/n,+\infty)\right))^c.$$
Since $f$ is LSC then for each $n$ the set $f^{-1}\left((b_j-1/n,+\infty)\right)$ is open $\Rightarrow$ $f^{-1}\left((b_j-1/n,+\infty)\right)\in \mathfrak{M}$ $\Rightarrow$ complement and countable union is also in $\mathfrak{M}$. Hence $f^{-1}(I_j)\in \mathfrak{M}$. Hence $f^{-1}(U)\in \mathfrak{M}$.

Am I right?

Comment: If $f$ is LSC then it can be shown that preimages wrt to $f$ of sets like $(a,\infty)$ are open (hence measurable in this context where the $\sigma$-algebra contains Borelsets). That allready is enough for $f$ to be a measurable function. Rays like $(a,\infty)$ are sufficient and easyer to handle than disjoint unions of open intervals.

Comment: @b00nheT, I guess that you're wrong. $f^{-1}(U)$ is disjoint ,i.e. $f^{-1}(A \sqcup B)=f^{-1}(A)\sqcup f^{-1}(B)$. I proved it quite strictly

Comment: @drhab, Yes you're right! Since we have criterion $f:X\to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable iff $\{x: f(x)>\alpha\}$ is measurable for any $\alpha$ real. Also $>$ can be replaced by $<,\leq, \geq$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Let's keep things easy :-).

Comment: @drhab, Thanks for nice remark! :)